# React Link doesn't trigger the router changement

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

In my react app I've tried lot of different router, route, and solution find on internet.

The fact is i'm using `<HashRouter>` from `react-router-dom` and redux in my app.

When I change the url in my browser the right route is triggered and the right component is loaded.

The issue :

When i click on `<Link>` component the url change, the `history` props on the router change but nothing happenned in the app...

Here are my app architecture and code :

**MainApp.jsx**

```
render(){
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
       <div className="main-app">
         <StickyContainer> 
           <Header toggleHelp={() => this.toggleOverlay()} />
           <Sticky>
                 <Toolbar /> //Here are my <Link/>     
           </Sticky>  
           <App/>
           <Footer />
         </StickyContainer>
       </div>
     </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as Actions from 'Actions';
import Main from 'Components/Main/Main';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = ({elements, actions,documents,filters}) => (
    <div>
      <Main elements={elements} actions={actions} documents={documents} filters={filters} />
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    elements: state.elements,
    documents: state.documents,
    filters:state.filters
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
});

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App));
```

And finally my **Main.jsx**

```
render(){
   <div className="main-authenticated">
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/reporting" component={Reporting} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/disconnect" component={ErrorPage} />
       </Switch>
   </div>
}
```

I already tried with a `BrowserRouter`, a basic `Router` with `history` but always this issue. Don't know if it's due to my project architecture or something else.

**UPDATE**

Moved `withRouter` on Main.jsx and got the same issue.

**Main.jsx**

```
render(){
   <div className="main-authenticated">
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/reporting" component={Reporting} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/disconnect" component={ErrorPage} />
       </Switch>
   </div>
}

export default withRouter(Main)
```

Comment: use withRouter with your Main.js, also check the duplicate

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I just moved withRouter on exporting Main. And got the same issue.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Find the solution... this was due to the Sticky component. When i remove it your solution works. If you reopen the question i can create the answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ShubhamKhatri said, I needed to export my Main component with `withRouter` function from `react-router`.

But there was an other issue, the `Link` included in the `Toolbar` component was not triggered the router due to the `Sticky` Component from `react-sticky`.

Remove the `Sticky` component wrapper on the `MainApp` correct the problem.

Final solution :

exporting Main.jsx

```
class Main 
[...]

export default withRouter(Main);
```

MainApp.jsx

```
 <Provider store={store}>
      <HashRouter>
         <div className="main-app">
           <Header />
           <Toolbar/>
           <App>
           <Footer />
        </div>
     </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
```